# Wordpress gives me "Error establishing a database connection" after I resolve "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" error in Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

I started to use WordPress in localhost a few weeks ago to realize a website for my degree thesis.

Yesterday, I started running Xampp but the function MySQL stopped immediately, with the following error:

> **Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.** 
> 02:06:56  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies 
> 02:06:56  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
> 02:06:56  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check 
> 02:06:56  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues 
> 02:06:56 [mysql]  If you need more help, copy and post this 
> 02:06:56  [mysql] entire log window on the forums

I managed to solve the problem replacing the Data folder in the Xampp files. 
 I renamed the Data folder in "Data_old", so I created a new "Data" folder. I copied the backup files in the new "Data" folder and, after that, I copy and pasted the site folder and the file "*ib_logfile1*" from the "Data_old".

When I tried to running MySQL function, it started without problems. But, when I tried to enter in Wordpress, it gives me "**Error establishing a database connection**". 
 How can I solve it?

Comment: Please share snip from mysqld.log covering the time of issue.

Comment: [Enable WordPress debug](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and see the log for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using MAMP but this error reminds me of a case I’ve encountered some time ago. In my case some references in the DB turned out to be the issue. Can you check if the permalinks in the {tableprefix}_posts table are correct? You can do so through DirectAdmin in xamp.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! 
I found the {tableprefix}_post you mentioned in the database structure, how can I check if the permalinks are correct?

Comment: It should match the root path in MAMP/XAMP:
-> Select your Host
-> Select the General-tab
-> Start your server if you haven't done so and click "Open"
The URL that's being opened should match the URL in the table. If that's not that case, your need to update your database (and maybe your wp_config.php file)